Euclidean algorithm in commutative rings with unity
Let R be a commutative ring with identity, and J an ideal generated by the members $a^n-1$ and $a^m-1$ for some $a \in R$ and $n, m$ positive integers.
I want to establish that the principal ideal generated by $a^d - 1$ where $d = gcd(m, n)$ (lets call it $I$) is infact equal to $J$.
Since I am not necessarily dealing with an integral domain (e.g. I could have zero divisors) and in particular its not necessarily a GCD domain, I do not get gcd-like elements "for free".
However, assuming $n > m$, I can express $a^n -1$ in terms of a linear combination (in $R$) of $a^{n-m}-1$ and $a^m-1$ and similary can express $a^{n-m}-1$ in terms of $a^n-1$ and $a^m-1$. Therefore the subring (ideal) generated by $(a^n-1, a^m-1)$ is the same as the one generated by $(a^{n-m}-1, a^m-1)$. I can now continue this downward iteration in similar fashion to the euclidean algorithm for finding GCD, and end up at a pair that looks like $(a^{gcd(m, n)}-1, a^{gcd(m, n)}-1)$ whence I deduce that the ideal generated by $a^d-1$ is the same as the one generated by $a^{n-m}-1$ and $a^m-1$.
Assuming we take the validity of the euclidean algorithm for finding an integral gcd as a given, does this reasoning apply? I am skeptical of my own way since I worry that there is a detail to do with possibility of zero divisors, and also the original question posed to me suggests a more roundabout route of establishing that $a$ is a unit in the quotient ring R/J and has order that is multiple of $d$ with respect to the multiplicative group of units in that quotient ring.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Most of the proofs in the dupe also work here. Alternatively specialize (evaluate) the (universal) Bezout equation in $\Bbb Z[x]$ to deduce that the gcd persists for elements of any ring, analogous to here. Similarly we can specialize any ideal equality in $\Bbb Z[x],,$ i.e. they are universal ideal equalities.

Your intuition seems right, but it may be easier to use what we have in $\mathbb{Z}$ rather than try to copy-paste it onto a new ring. This will avoid concerns about new factors (e.g. presence of zerodivisors) from becoming relevant. I have given one solution below as an example of working in $\mathbb{Z}$ and then applying that to $R$.
I would guess that the recommended solution is recommended for the same reason: to avoid thinking about too many moving parts.

First, consider the following:
Fact: If $f|g$, say $g =fn$, then $a^f-1$ divides $a^g-1$. This is because we can write:
$$(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^{if})(a^f-1) = a^g-1$$
We will use this fact twice below.
Write $d = xn + ym$ via Bezout’s Lemma. Then:
$$a^d-1 = a^{xn+ym}-1 = a^{xn}(a^{ym}-1) + a^{xn}-1$$
and by the above fact, as $a^{xn}-1$ and $a^{ym}-1$ are respectively in $(a^n-1)$ and $(a^m-1)$, we have that $a^d-1$ is in their sum.
However, we already have that $a^d-1$ divides both of them, so applying the above fact we are done.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

Got it - thank you and sorry for this being a dupe I looked at other threads but they seemed to be more specific eg to integer rings or polynomial rings so I thought there is value in posing the more general question but perhaps it is superfluous in any case
